# How can I get the ISO format for date and time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs, iso8601

I have two separate fields of date and time:-

```
const date = 2020-12-10;
const time = 22:00;
```

expected output:-

```
2020-12-10T10:00:00Z
```

I'm following this approach but the time in coming wrong:-

```
const date = DateUtil.getFullDateString(this.state.date_value);
const time = moment(this.state.time_value, ['HH.mm']).format('hh:mm a');
const momentObj = moment(date + time, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm');
const dateTime = momentObj.toISOString();

the output of time is coming 18:30:00 but need to have 10:00:00

2020-12-10T18:30:00Z
```

Comment: `date + "T" + time + ":00Z"`? Assuming your fields are in UTC, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: the fields are not in UTC

Comment: First you say you expect 22:00 to become 10:00, indicating you're at +12, then you expect 18:30 but are getting 10:00, indicating you're at -8:30. You're formatting *time* as "hh:mm a" (i.e. 12 hour time) then parsing it as "HH:mm" (24 hour time).

Answer (score 1):

You could parse date and time one by one, then add time to date and finally format as you want.

```js
const date = '2020-12-10';
const time = '22:00';

const momentDate = moment(date).utc().startOf('day'); // utc() to avoid the offset
console.log(momentDate);
const momentTime = moment(time, 'HHmm').format('HH:mm');
console.log(momentTime);
const resultTime = momentDate.add(momentTime);
console.log(resultTime);

// Format as you want
console.log(resultTime.format('LLL'));
console.log(resultTime.format('YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.SSSA[Z]'));
console.log(resultTime.toISOString());
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

See [this](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3086) in order to know how to manage the UTC offset.

Comment: `moment(date).utc().startOf('day')` isn't a good idea as it may shift the date ±1 day depending on when the code is run and the host offset. For me it's currently returning "2020-12-09T22:00:00.000Z" which is not what the OP wants. The answer in VLAZ's comment is very much more efficient and not error prone.